# my android app facing voice disappear issue with agora

Tags: android, android-studio, agora.io

my Agora Live App Id -
0795049c389f40d99cbb1a67cc983c18

This problem occurred since 18 March midnight. How do i need to fix it?

my user are leaving bad reviews on playstore

Comment: And just based on this someone should know what the problem is?

Comment: Okay, as you van see on the title, i have facing voice disappearance problem, while talking in the middle..

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have upgraded the Agora SDK version to the latest. https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/release_android_video?platform=Android

If the issue still occurs after the upgrade, please file a Jira ticket and Agora support team will help you. https://agora-ticket.agora.io/

Comment: thanx but i found out the problem, the problem is happneing due to screen off foregorund service, since google annouce theire new update that they no more support the foreground service above thean oreo since im continue to fixing this issue but im still getiing lot of hurdle in my way,, if you have simple solution that how can i solve this issue then please reach out to me - somitrov@gmail.com